# Water leaking from the top of "Aqua Stop" (water inlet) during the final cycle of washing machine

Tags: leak, washing-machine

Front-Loading washing machine.

All washing works fine, but during the final fast spin cycle, water leaks from the top of the "Aqua Stop hose" thing which is connected to the inlet.

Water looks clean and odourless. What might be causing water to flow out of this during the final spin? Please see attached picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u46Qc.jpg

Comment: What make/model of washer?

Comment: I think it is one of these: https://cdn.globalauctionplatform.com/af647a58-c820-48f4-bc65-a50900912255/56931af0-55af-497d-a8f6-03d96ebfdc04/540x360.jpg AEG protex